How to update just magento 2 via composer
What is the correct way to update just Magento core without extensions via composer?
If I run:
composer require-commerce magento/product-community-edition 2.4.6-p7 --no-update
composer update
it updates everything, all the extensions etc.
Thanks!

You can update certain packages as follows
Run an update test to check all packages to be updated.

composer update "magento/*" -W --dry-run

Run the Update

composer update "magento/*" -W


--with-all-dependencies (-W): Update also dependencies of packages in the argument list, including those which are root requirements.
--dry-run: Simulate the command without actually doing anything.

You can check docs of composer update here https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#update-u-upgrade
What's more, you can view all the packages used by Magento on their github.
https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4-develop/composer.json

Thank you DJX, that works like a charm.
